# Does this pseudo-holomorphic triangle contribute to the product $\mu_2$ in Lagrangian Floer cohomology?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, floer-homology, fukaya-category

I'm computing the product map $$\mu_2 : CF(L_0,V)\otimes CF(V,L_1)\to CF(L_0,L_1)$$ in Seidel's exact triangle for this specific case:

[image: genus 2]

This is a genus 2 surface, and I color-coded the three (Lagrangian) circles I'm interested in.

As far as I can see, there are 2 embedded triangles ($T_1,T_2$) with the correct orientation:

[image]

and a 3rd one (T3) which is not embedded but looks immersed nonetheless:

[image]

whose disk-like "nature" can be better seen by lifting to a double cover of the surface:

[image]

My problem with triangle T3 is that it looks rigid since it comes from a rigid one in the cover, but according to a classical theorem from FOOO, such triangles should be in natural bijection with bigons bounded by $L_0$ and $\tau_{V}L_1$ (I believe it's part of the proof that we have a long exact sequence for the Lagrangian surgery $V\# L_1$ - see [Auroux's intro's to Fukaya cats](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.7056.pdf) page 29). For T1 and T2 their corresponding bigons are immediate to found, while for T3 I cannot.

Should T3 count for the map $\mu_2$? if not, why?